# c++ How to draw a region given a set of points?

Tags: c++, opencv

**Note**: I'm coding in C++

I got four points of a irregular shape.

```
cv::Point(myshape[0].x, myshape[0].y) // [  3, 5 ]
cv::Point(myshape[1].x, myshape[1].y) // [ 13, 9 ]
cv::Point(myshape[2].x, myshape[2].y) // [  1, 18]
cv::Point(myshape[3].x, myshape[3].y) // [ 16, 22]
```

that should look like this:

[image]

And I'd like to draw a filled shape of it's contour with the given 4 points to get a **Mat** like this *(of course not including these rounded corners, thats my fault, ignore this)*:

[image]

How can I achieve to draw a filled shape like this by it's 4 corner points?

**Note**: There will be 4 corner points in every case.

---

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks a million in advance, Tempi.

**Note**: The code I got so far *(not working)*

```
Mat myMask;
myMask.setTo(0);

vector<cv::Points> myVector;
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) myVector.push_back(myPoints[i]);
//cv::fillPoly(myMask, myVector, 0, 1, cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
approxPolyDP(myVector, ROI_Poly, 1.0, true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Found the solution on my own, so simple :)

Maybe somebody needs the solution later, so here you go

```
Mat result;
myImage.copyTo(result); // keep the size of the image
result.setTo(0); // Make mask black

vector<cv::Point> ROI_Poly;
approxPolyDP(myVector, ROI_Poly, 1.0, true); // draw contour of myVector points
fillConvexPoly(result, &ROI_Poly[0], ROI_Poly.size(), Scalar(255, 255, 255), 8, 0); // fill drawed contour white
```

**Note**: To avoid the warning at this line: `fillConvexPoly(result, &ROI_Poly[0], ROI_Poly.size(), Scalar(255, 255, 255), 8, 0);`

... just change the line to :

`fillConvexPoly(result, &ROI_Poly[0], (int)ROI_Poly.size(), Scalar(255, 255, 255), 8, 0);`